# Adding a horizontal Progress Bar to each List View item like the Data Usage activity

Tags: android, android-progressbar

In Android's built in Data Usage activity, each List View has a horizontal progress bar displaying the relative value for each block (http://www.oneclickroot.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Android-Ice-Cream-Sandwich-Data-Usage-1024x640.jpg). How can I add one to my xml file, and update it in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Use this attribute: style="@style/ProgressBar.Horizontal.Bar" on the XML file for Status Bars.

See this link for implementation code: http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out. I don't think its the same thing though.

Comment: It's not the same thing by default,  by I believe it is if you make it wider.